# Foundation 5 new project: git issues

Tags: git, zurb-foundation

I feel I'm going crazy about this.

I'm trying to **start a new project with Foundation 5** and I get a very strange issue related to my git repo. I've been using Foundation 4 before and I have check I meet all the requirements (git, ruby +1.9, node, etc).

I want to use Foundation with compass. We have a server where private git repos are stored so, as usual, I first create a git repo and create a new folder for it, lets say `Documents/client`. Then I create a foundation project inside, for example `cd Documents/client foundation new my_project`. No errors.

Foundation 5 creates the folder my_project with everything inside (bower_components, config.rb, etc). But when I try to **add my_project to my repo**, I can see it's being added as a submodule, apparently because there's already a git repo inside my_project.

What I find weird is that 
 
a) I can see some local commits related to Foundation development made by @mhayes
b) If I look for these commits on [foundation repo](https://github.com/zurb/bower-foundation/commits/master) I cannot find them 
c) I don't have a remote to pull from

I admit my knwoledge of Git is quite basic but I've never had this kind of problems with Foundation 4, though I know that using bower makes things quite different but I'm totally stuck.

Also, I can't find much documentation (Foundation docs are so minimal!) and the help Forum is not working (can't sign in), so no need to say any help will be much appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

I finally deleted the .git folder inside `my_project` but left the `.gitignore` inside and now my repo (with `client` folder as root) seems to be working fine: no more Foundation related commits plus I have a remote I can push to / pull from.

Apparently that solved the issue, though I still would like to know if this solution is good practice or just kind of a nasty fix... I don't think it's normal behaviour that I get a git repo when creating a project with `foundation new`...

Answer (score 0):

Your finding are correct.

Once you have `.git` folder inside another git folder git doesn't like it too much.
The way to handle it is pretty simple:

1. Add the inner `.git` folder to the `.gitignore`.
2. Set the inner project as submodule.

> Submodules allow you to keep a Git repository as a subdirectory of another Git repository. This lets you clone another repository into your project and keep your commits separate.